# Simple onclick javascript scroller

Tags: image, scroll

I have a question regarding the site im developing at the moment. It has a simple image scroller in footer. The question is how to make it scrolling with a simple javascript? I don´t want any fancy plugins because it´s not that advanced scroller. i´ve attached a picture. thanks to all who take time to answer.

[image: scroller on footer]

Answer (score 0):

You can get started right here: http://symmetrycode.com/javascript-horizontal-scroll-website/

Tell me if it doesn't works.